# scaling images in original ratio on hover using transform of css3?

Tags: css

im trying to resize image on hover....but we can only specify static length values and no % values in transform:scale of css3 i guess. Example:

```
#imgp:hover{-webkit-transform: scale(7,6);transform: scale(7,6);}
```

but using above the wide images are showing with equal dimensions ie. square.
how to show with original ratio ? is it possible ?

Comment: Then don't scale both axes, just one. You are sacling now x and y axis, scale just one.

Comment: it's showing as square on using one value ! (-webkit-transform: scale(7))

Comment: Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/83BgY/

Comment: @drip: does it do something on hover, PS what OP says?

Comment: You are looking it under webkit, and I didn't add webkit prefix for it, that's why you don't see a thing. (I'm firefox user sry xd)

Comment: @drip: right, working fine.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're trying it for a square image, scaling in only one dimension will solve the problem:

See Fiddle by @drip.

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/83BgY/]
```